# Twilio passing parametes through Twilio.Device.connect

Tags: php, twilio

Hi there I have three pieces of code namely:

1. browser-record
2. browser-record-twiml
3. recording-goodbye

Objective: To pass external values(e.g. merchantID) and store it in a database
The flow of Code:

`browser-record.php -> browser-record-twiml.php->recording-goodbye.php`

Please help me out with this,
My Boss is breathing heavily down my neck,

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Connect lets you provide a parameters collection, which is basically a dictionary.  For example, in JavaScript you might do something like this:

```
params = { "PhoneNumber": $("#number").val() };
Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

This snippet creates an array in Javascript, setting the key to PhoneNumber and grabbing the value from an HTML element named *number*, then passes that to the connect function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have been looking all over for documentation on what are valid parameters to pass.  I see "PhoneNumber" in the Quick Start, and "client" in the How-To for browser-to-browser.  The former seems to work for actually calling my browser client - the latter calls something that gives a default "Contratulations" message.  What I don't understand is what Twilio does with these params under the covers.  From the How-To, it seems that the "client" parameter gets passed in the request to the page hosting the TwiML (though it doesn't work for me).  Is NREZ asking how he can pass additional variables?

Comment: In my example above the params variable is just a dictionary.  You can put whatever key/value pairs you want into it.  Twilio will take those key/value pairs and pass them to you as GET or POST parameters when it makes the request to the TwiML App URL.